# ¿Cómo colocar alerta con JavaScript para condicionar introducción de datos en input number?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

```
`<?php
require "../conexion.php";
    $cedula_productor=$_POST['cedula_productor'];

    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT (cedula_productor) FROM productor_principal WHERE cedula_productor='$cedula_productor'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>0)
        {
            $consulta="SELECT * FROM productor_principal WHERE cedula_productor='$cedula_productor'";
            $resultado=mysql_query($consulta,$con);
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
            {
        $tipo_identificacion= $row['tipo_identificacion'];

                $cedula_productor= $row['cedula_productor'];
                $datos_productor= $row['datos_productor'];

        $vacas= $row['vacas'];
        $toros= $row['toros'];
        $novillas= $row['novillas'];
        $novillos= $row['novillos'];
        $mautas= $row['mautas'];
        $mautes= $row['mautes'];
        $becerras= $row['becerras'];
        $becerros= $row['becerros'];
 }
?>

<h2>CERTIFICADO  DE VACUNACIÓN</h2>
  
<form action="certificado_productor.php" method="POST">

<table class="table1">

<tr>
  <th colspan="2">
      <label for="name1">NOMBRE DUEÑO DEL ANIMAL</label>
      <input type="hidden" name="datos_duenio_animal" value="<?php  echo $datos_productor; ?>">
      <br><?php  echo $datos_productor; ?>
  </th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>
    <h3>DESCRIPCIÓN DE LOS ANIMAL</h3>
 </th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>
    <h3>BOVINOS</h3>
 </th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <font color=#333><B>VACAS</B>
  </td>

  <td>
    <font color=#333><B>TOROS</B>
  </td>
    
  <td>
    <font color=#333><B>NOVILLAS</B>
 </td>

 <td>
    <font color=#333><B>NOVILLOS</B>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="vacas_vacunacion" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $vacas; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="vacas" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $vacas; ?>" >
    <font color=#333>EXISTENTE EN PREDIO:<?php  echo $vacas; ?>
  </td>



  <td>
    <input type="number" name="toros_vacunacion" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="toros" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $toros; ?>" >
    <font color=#333>EXISTENTE EN PREDIO:<?php  echo $toros; ?>
  </td>
    
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="novillas_vacunacion" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="novillas" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $novillas; ?>" >
    <font color=#333>EXISTENTE EN PREDIO:<?php  echo $novillas; ?>
 </td>



 <td>
  <input type="number" name="novillos_vacunacion" class="form-control">
  <input type="hidden" name="novillos" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $novillos; ?>" >
  <font color=#333>EXISTENTE EN PREDIO:<?php  echo $novillos; ?>

 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <font color=#333><B>MAUTAS</B>
  </td>

  <td>
    <font color=#333><B>MAUTES</B>
  </td>
      
  <td>
    <font color=#333><B>BECERRAS</B>
  </td>

  <td>
    <font color=#333><B>BECERROS</B>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="mautas_vacunacion" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="mautas" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $mautas; ?>" >
    <font color=#333>EXISTENTE EN PREDIO:<?php  echo $mautas; ?>
  </td>

  <td>
    <input type="number" name="mautes_vacunacion" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="mautes" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $mautes; ?>" >
    <font color=#333>EXISTENTE EN PREDIO:<?php  echo $mautes; ?>

  </td>
    
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="becerras_vacunacion" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="becerras" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $becerras; ?>" >
    <font color=#333>EXISTENTE EN PREDIO:<?php  echo $becerras; ?>

 </td>

 <td>
    <input type="number" name="becerros_vacunacion" class="form-control">
    <input type="hidden" name="becerros" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $becerros; ?>" >
    <font color=#333>EXISTENTE EN PREDIO:<?php  echo $becerros; ?>
 </td>
</tr>

<?php
?>
```

`[image]

Hola, tengo un formulario, con datos previamente registrados en una de las tablas de mi base de datos, pero en este formulario, se almacenará en otra tabla, pero en concordancia entre ambas tablas. Ahora bien, acá esta el formulario, donde muestra la existencia de ganado bovino en una tabla, y con este formulario, se esta registrando el ganado bovino vacunado, que se guardará en otra tabla. LO que quiero es que al momento de ingresar, la cantidad ingresada sea mayor a la existencia, mande una alerta indicando que es mayor la cantidad.

Comment: Siempre agrega el codigo con el cual estas trabajando

Answer (score 1):

Te Recomiendo usar SweetAlert y te quedaría un ejemplo como el de recién, la librería es excelente y podes hacer muchísimas cosas.

'

Swal.fire({
icon: 'error',
title: 'Oops...',
text: 'la cantidad ingresada es mayor a la que existe',

```js
$(".boton").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'la cantidad ingresada es mayor a la que existe.!',
  confirmButtonText:
    '<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Aceptar!',
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<button id="<?php echo $valor['id'];>"class="boton">
Borrar                                                     </button>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.0.11/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="sweetalert/functions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!
footer: 'Why do I have this issue?'
})

Comment: Hola Santiago, es buena librería, pero el problema aquí, es como colocar una alerta en tiempo real,  teniendo en cuenta que se esta trabajando con mysql, ya que los datos estan previamente registrados,  y los que se ingresaran, seran almacenados en otra tabla.

Comment: Ejemplo del formulario. Si tengo cierta cantidad de animales, supongamos 10 animales registrados, logicamente los animales que se van a vacunar tienen 10 o menos animales, si se ingresa en ese input 12, me muestre una alerta que el numero ingresado es mayor.